# About NixNote and note taking alternatives

Tags: notes, evernote

Since I think Evernote fits my needs as a note taking application, I considered NixNote as a natural candidate for a desktop side note taking application.

There is little information about NixNote, but as far as I have understood it is an Evernote client. I am wondering whether synchronisation with Evernote is necessary or NixNote can be used as a stand alone application, only for offline use and local storage of data (thus avoiding Evernote free account limits). In case this would not be possible, what alternative would you suggest?

Of Evernote I mainly appreciate the organisation of notes in different notebooks, text formatting and more important the possibility to insert files, images, links, videos, audio...

Answer (score 1):

Here are few alternatives:

- FromScratch.
- Cherrytree
- Springseed
- Turtl

Comment: I already considered Springseed but it seems that getspringseed.com is for a few days now unreacheable.

Comment: Indeed...there is also an issue opened in github. You try pulling it from github and compile it: https://github.com/byhestia/springseed
I will also try it later.

Comment: Check this out: https://turtl.it/

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at ThetaPad (http://thetapad.com)! It is cross platform, simple and user friendly.

It is like CherryTree but supports cloud synchronization, works much better with images. It also supports cross-references between documents to speed-up navigation between notes.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It is like CherryTree but supports cloud synchronization, works much better with images. It also supports cross-references between documents to speed-up navigation between notes